# SharePoint 2010 - enable custom ribbon button only if user has permission to edit selected item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom action in a ribbon, and I need to enable the button only if current user has permission to edit the item (Contribute role). I have a PageComponent to tell the UI if command can be handled, but I can figure out how to check user permissions for an item in javascript.

This is in my PageComponent:

```
        canHandleCommand: function (commandId) {
            switch (commandId) {
                case 'Command1':
                    var ids = getSelectedIds(); // gets an array of selected ids

                    var selectionChanged = false;
                    if (ids.length != this.previousIds.length) {
                        selectionChanged = true;
                    } else {
                        for (var index in ids) {
                            if (ids[index] != this.previousIds[index]) {
                                selectionChanged = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (selectionChanged) {
                        this.enabledStatusChecked = false;
                    }

                    this.previousIds = ids;

                    if (!this.enabledStatusChecked) {
                        this.checkIsEnabled(ids);
                    }

                    return this.isEnabled;
            }

            return false;
        },
        checkIsEnabled: function (ids) {
            this.enabledStatusChecked = true;
            this.isEnabled = false;

            if (ids.length != 1) {
                return;
            }

            var id = ids[0];

            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();

            var list = web.get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());
            var item = list.getItemById(id);

            context.load(item);
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
                var contentTypeId = item.get_item('ContentTypeId').toString();
                if (!contentTypeId.lastIndexOf(Constants.InternalNormContentTypeId, 0)) {
                    this.isEnabled = true;
                    // !! need to check permissions here !!
                }
                RefreshCommandUI();
            }), Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
                RefreshCommandUI();
            }));
        },
```

This code enables the button only if 1 item is selected and if it is of specified content type. Does anybody have any idea about how to check permission through javascript?

Answer (score 1):

from my point of view. You have two ways, the first adding tag in html/master page:
http://buyevich.blogspot.com/2010/08/hide-ribbon-from-visitorsanonimus-users_31.html
or created asp control and also take it to page:
http://dicemastersharespoint.blogspot.com/2011/02/hiding-buttonscontrols-on-sharepoint.html

Write back whether possible for your solution or not.

Best Regards

Martin

Comment: No. These solutions work if you know what permissions user has on server. But I require to enable/disable the button every time user selects different item (that means no postback), and I have different permissions set on each item.